# Expand a complex list object within a tibble to bigger tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(fpp2) # for prison dataset
library(hts) # forecasting function

# prepare group time series
prison.gts <- gts(prison/1e3, characters = c(3,1,9),
                  gnames = c("State", "Gender", "Legal",
                             "State*Gender", "State*Legal",
                             "Gender*Legal"))

result_prison <- tidyr::crossing(methods = c('bu', 'comb'), 
                              fmethod = c('arima')) %>%
  mutate(forecast_result = purrr::map2(methods, fmethod, 
                                       ~forecast.gts(prison.gts,method = .x, fmethod = .y)))


result_prison
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  methods fmethod forecast_result
  <chr>   <chr>   <list>         
1 bu      arima   <gts>          
2 comb    arima   <gts>
```

result_prison contains a column named forecast_result which is defined as a list.

In particular, I'm interested to extract the following data from forecast_result list into one big tibble without any 'list' object.

```
result_prison$forecast_result[[1]]$bts
result_prison$forecast_result[[1]]$histy
result_prison$forecast_result[[1]]$method # this is actually the same value from column methods
result_prison$forecast_result[[1]]$fmethod # this is actually the same value from column fmethods
```

Ideally, I think a better tibble version is when the list objects are expanded such that I have one big tibble with usual types like char, double, etc. No list objects.

I tried

```
result_prison %>%
  hoist(forecast_result, 
        hoisted_method = "method",
        hoisted_fmethod = "fmethod",
        bts = "bts",
        histy = 'histy'
  )
```

Though I still ended up with a list of time series object within the tibble.

Answer (score 0):

These ideas would work if the last column were `dataframes`. Since it is not, I suspect you need to extract the entries one at a time:

```
result_prison %>% pluck("forecast_result", 1)
result_prison %>% pluck("forecast_result", 2)
```